# Stop method execution until another activity finished

Tags: java, android

Good day to everyone!

I need to stop method execution until another activity will end.
At the moment I'm trying to do it in this way:

```
    private boolean isPausedWhileSplash;

public void showSplashWorldChangeAd(String oldWorldName, String newWorldName) {
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashScreen.class);
    intent.putExtra(SplashScreen.MSG_STRING_KEY, oldWorldName + " -> "
            + newWorldName);
    intent.putExtra(SplashScreen.OLD_WORLD, oldWorldName);
    intent.putExtra(SplashScreen.NEW_WORLD, newWorldName);
    startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_OK);
    isPausedWhileSplash = true;
    while (isPausedWhileSplash) {
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    isPausedWhileSplash = false;
}
```

But it's not working.

Can you help me?

Thanks!

**UPD:** Maybe there is any way to prevent view from drawing? Because all what I need right now is delay calling of methods, which will redraw view of this activity. Now I have the new world drawn before the splash screen, saying about the world change, is shown, which is not looking good.

Comment: What are you trying to do in that other Activity?

Comment: Relying on the other `Activity` to end isn't a good way to arrange the flow of your application.

Comment: `while (isPausedWhileSplash) {}` is just going to sit and eat CPU for no reason. You need to use a lock or other thread-signalling mechanism.

Comment: Other activity shows some kind of a Splash Screen.

Comment: @Basic, can I ask you to give some example in answer? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a little rushed for time so here's a generic answer:

```
public class MonitorObject{
}

public class MyWaitNotify{

  MonitorObject myMonitorObject = new MonitorObject(); //To be used for synch

  public void doWait(){
    synchronized(myMonitorObject){
      try{
        myMonitorObject.wait(); // Wait until the notify method is called by another thread
      } catch(InterruptedException e){...}
    }
  }

  public void doNotify(){ //Notify waiting threads that they can continue
    synchronized(myMonitorObject){
      myMonitorObject.notify();
    }
  }
}
```

I'll come back and get you a working example this afternoon if you haven't got a solution by then...

[This article](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/thread-signaling.html) should get you started

**EDIT:** [This article](http://www.aviyehuda.com/blog/2010/12/20/android-multithreading-in-a-ui-environment/) demonstrates other approaches, all of which should be an improvement on your current solution. It talks you through how to update the UI from events in different threads and the benefits/costs of the various solutions.

Comment: Thanks! This is very good example. But I think in that way it blocks the thread, in which the code is executed, because I can't manage this to work, and I think it's because the main thread is blocked(I don't create any other threads)

Comment: Ah, I apologise as I'd misunderstood - It does indeed block thread 1 until thread n signals that it is complete. a) You may want to consider using multiple threads as it makes it far easier to keep track of things and b) you may well be using multiple threads without realising it - events work by starting a new thread to handle the event `onActivityResult` implies an event model - A new thread will call that method while the old thread continues. In either case, have a read of that article as it may give you some ideas

Comment: @MaksymStakhieiev Have a look at the article linked in my edit. Perhaps that would be more appropriate for you?

Comment: I read the article, it shows almost all ways of using multi-threading in Android. But unfortunately it can't help in my case, and I think the best way this far is to change the design of the whole program, using the advises from those articles. Thanks! :)

Comment: @MaksymStakhieiev No worries. Sorry, I couldn't give you a simpler answer. Good luck and welcome to SO.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to do something like this:

```
public void showSplashWorldChangeAd(String oldWorldName, String newWorldName){
    /* You have done some initialization work */
    startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_OK);
    /* This is what you want to do after the activity returns */
    afterActivityReturns();
}
```

Then why not proceed this way?

```
public void showSplashWorldChangeAd(String oldWorldName, String newWorldName){
        /* You have done some initialization task here*/
        startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_OK);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        /* This is what you want to do after the activity finishes */
        afterActivityReturns();
    }
```

But if you really want to stop the `showSplashWorldChangeAd` method for some reason, you need lock and key (as Basic says).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It's really the best way to do things, but in my case all work is done in another method, started after this method is finished, that's why I need to stop the execution of method, so there is no return until the called activity is over